# Expectation of sub-R-Gaussian

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Suppose $\{\xi_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is a real-valued stochastic process such that $\xi_i$ is $F_{i}$ measurable and $\xi_i$ is conditionally $\sigma$-sub-Gaussian for some $\sigma\geq 0$, which means
$$
E[\exp (\lambda \xi_i)|F_{i-1}]\leq \exp (\frac{\lambda^2\sigma^2}{2})~~~\forall \lambda \in R
$$

My question is, whether the following is true
$$
E[\exp (\xi_j\xi_i)|F_{i-1}]\leq \exp (\frac{\xi_j^2\sigma^2}{2})~~~\forall j<i
$$
and 
$$
E[\exp (\xi_j\xi_i)|F_{i-1}]\leq \exp (\frac{\xi_i^2\sigma^2}{2})~~~\forall j<i
$$

The intuition is to consider $\xi_i$ and $\xi_j$ as $\lambda$ in definition. Moreover, how about functions of $\xi_i$ and $\xi_j$.
$$
E[\exp (f(\xi_j)\xi_i)|F_{i-1}]\leq \exp (\frac{f(\xi_j)^2\sigma^2}{2})~~~\forall j<i
$$
and 
$$
E[\exp (\xi_jf(\xi_i))|F_{i-1}]\leq \exp (\frac{f(\xi_i)^2\sigma^2}{2})~~~\forall j<i
$$

Comment: Do you mean that $\xi_i$ is $\mathcal F_i$-measurable?

Comment: Oh yes, I've corrected it.

Comment: I seems to be true when $(\xi_i)_i$ is independent and $F_i$ is the natural filtration. I will think on the general case.